# angular page parameters get appended to url in safari

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2, angular-routing, angular6

I have a material angular app. The first page is a login page which on successful login gets replaced by homepage. In case of safari, what i see is that username password are appended to the url after login. I do not expect this to happen and in chrome it does not happen.

**The Login page looks like:**

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="doLogin()">
              <div><input matInput placeholder=" User ID" name="userId" [(ngModel)]="userId" ></div>
              <div><input matInput type="password" name="password" placeholder=" Password" [(ngModel)]="password"></div>

              <div><button mat-raised-button  (click)="doLogin()">Sign In</button></div>
            </form>
```

**login.ts**

```
     userId:string
      password:string

     doLogin(){
 this.errorMessage = ''
    if(this.userId == undefined  || this.userId == ''){
      this.errorMessage = 'Authentication Failed'
      return
    }

    var user:UserModel = this.dataStore.findUser(this.userId.trim().toLowerCase())
    if(user == undefined || (user.password != this.password)){
       this.errorMessage = 'Authentication Failed'
      return
    }

    this.core.currentUser = user.userId
          this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
      }
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginPageComponent
    },
     {
        path: 'homepage',
        component: DynamicHomeComponent
    }

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

On login the url becomes below in case of safari:
https://myurl/homepage?userid=xxx&password=yyy

Comment: What is your doLogin function? Is it just that placeholder? Are you sending the username and password as url parameters, if so, that's wrong...

Comment: right that would be foolish to pass user and pwd as url paramters. I am not doing that at least intentionally. and this does not happen in chrome. i just added my complete login code i have

Comment: use this html instead tell me if it still happens `<div>
 <div><input matInput placeholder=" User ID" name="userId" [(ngModel)]="userId"></div>
 <div><input matInput type="password" name="password" placeholder=" Password" [(ngModel)]="password"></div>

 <div><button mat-raised-button (click)="doLogin()">Sign In</button></div>
</div>`

Comment: it seems form tag is causing this issue. removing it works fine. nt sure why though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you have a `<form>` tag, that does not properly implement `<form>`. If you want to use the form tag use the `<button type="submit"></button>` syntax on your submit button. Here you have a button that has a `(click)` method AND you have a `submit` method on the form tag. The default submit which is a get request with url params corresponding to the forms `input`s is being run since your button does not have a `type="submit"` and has click event.

tl;dr => Use the conventions of html form or just use the click event but not both.